# jsDoc @param for any html element

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I've been searching for ages but cant find anything that allows me to document any htmlelement as a parameter for example I have the below:

```
/**
 * input an element with children to remove all children
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement} node - the html element that we want to remove children from
 */

function removeChildrenFromNode(node) {
    if (node === undefined || node === null) {
        return;
    }
    while (node.firstChild) {
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }
}
```

How do I specify that `node` can be any html element? Because I am getting a warning when passing in a div.

Comment: That is strange because HTMLDivElement has for a prototype HTMLElement. What gives you that warning?

Comment: phpStorm it reports : Argument type Element is not assignable to parameter type HTMLElement

Comment: I do not have access to phpStorm so I cannot reproduce this warning, but if you pass a div why does phpStorm think that you are passing an Element (which is the prototype of HTMLElement) instead of a HTMLDivElement?

Comment: My guess is that you are using a function or a property that returns Element by specification. Try use {Element} then.

Comment: perfect that appears to have solved the issue